# I installed TensorFlow and found no modules found

Tags: python, tensorflow

I downloaded it by pip install tensorflow in cmd

The installation is fine and I have tensorflow when I pip list and look at the list.

in Python,

`import tensorflow`

but can't find the module.

I can't install it with pip3.

What should I do?

Comment: Hi, please provide precise error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have multiple python versions installed.You can use cmd
'**where python**' on windows to find which python you are running and also verify where you have install tenserflow module using pip.